newaliases in script results in permission denied
Running Ubuntu. After updating the /etc/aliases file, the newaliases command must be run to build an alias database /etc/aliases.db. I can successfully run sudo newaliases but when I created a shell script (named myscript.sh) that uses the newaliases command, I am getting postalias: fatal: open /etc/aliases.db: Permission denied error. I use sudo myscript.sh to start the script (whoami executed by the script prints out 'root') and the script successfully executes multiple commands that require root privileges (e.g. writes to /etc/aliases) prior to hitting the error with newaliases.
I attempted the following:

verified the access of /etc/aliases and /etc/aliases.db commands - both are 755 root:root
changed the attributes of myscript.sh to 755 root:root
changed the attributes of myscript.sh to 4755 root:root
instead of running newaliases, I tried postalias /etc/aliases as well as sendmail -bi as they seem to provide similar functionality
updated the sudoers configuration to allow no-password execution of newaliases:

myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/myscript.sh
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/newaliases


allowed my user to execute any commands with sudo:

myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL


used sudo newaliases in the script
used sudo bash -c "newaliases" in the script

All the above attempts failed - always getting the same error.
Main question: how can I execute newaliases from a shell script? Any idea what is special about newaliases given the fact that the script performs other actions requiring root access without issues?
What I discovered during step 4 is that newaliases is just a symlink to sendmail:
ubuntu@mail:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/newaliases
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jan 29  2024 /usr/bin/newaliases -> ../sbin/sendmail

but when I simply run sendmail it does NOT perform the update of the alias database just like newaliases does (instead it needs the sendmail -bi command to do the same). This is the secondary question - if you can explain this mystery it may help.
Thanks!
JJ

I am not able to reproduce this with a minimal script with echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/bin/newaliases'.

The sendmail binary probably looks at argv[0] (name it's being invoked with) to figure out what to do, so I don't think that is relevant.

What happens if you delete the .db file before running your script?

The permissions are wrong on your two data files.  Try as root rm /etc/aliases.db; chmod 644 /etc/aliases then run your script with sudo again.

your suggestion was great and helped me find the problem - there was an error earlier in the script that changed the owner of the /etc/aliases file.

sounds like a reasonable explanation: "it is possible that the sendmail binary looks at argv[0] to figure out what to do" - thank you Alan!

Alan's suggestion was great to simplify the script to just:
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/newaliases

this simple script worked and it helped to find me an error in the earlier code of the original script which unintentionally modified the owner of the /etc/aliases file to not be root. This causes the newaliases command to fail.

FYI simplifying your script to contain a [mcve] is a required step for any question, see [ask].
